# Format the form data to send to the server

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

This is the form

```
 this.participantForm = this.fb.group({
      occupation: [null],
      occupationAddress: [null],
      symptoms: new FormArray([])
  })
```

This is the value I have after user selected options in the form,

```
  {
  "occupation": 2,
  "occupationAddress": "B23 IND",
  "symptoms": [
    "N",
    "Y",
    "Y"
  ]
}
```

There is an another array, symptoms value in the participant form should merge.

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
]
```

Once merged, the participant form data will look like this. This is the formatneed to send to server on save.

```
  {
  "occupation": null,
  "occupationAddress": null,
  "symptomsResult": [
     {
    "symptomId": 8651,
    "symptomValue": "N"
  },
  {
    "symptomId": 8646,
    "symptomValue": "Y"
  },
  {
    "symptomId": 8642,
    "symptomValue": "Y"
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just use a simple map using index

```
const dataSend={...this.participantForm.value,
                   symptomsResult:this.data.map((data:any,index:number)=>(
                   {
                     symptomId:data.id
                     symptomValue:this.participantForm.value.symptoms[index]
                   })
                   )
               }
```

::glups:: I missed. I think that the form.value has "symptomsResult" (but is symptoms", so the correct is:

```
const dataSend={occupation:this.participantForm.value.occupation,
                occupationAddress:this.participantForm.value.occupationAddress,
                symptomsResult:this.data.map((data:any,index:number)=>(
                   {
                     symptomId:data.id
                     symptomValue:this.participantForm.value.symptoms[index]
                   })
                   )
               }
```

Comment: symptomsResult:this.data.map((data:any;index:number)=> : getting this error on this line .................'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Comment: sorry, is ",", not ";". but it's important you understand the function. I get all the properties of this.participantForm.value using the "spread operator" (after I take account that the name of the variables are not corrected, and in the updated it's ok) , but override the property "symptomsResult". The property symptomsResult is an array. how do you get the array), using  map transform the array "this.data" in an object with two properties: 'symptomId', that get the value of the "id", and symptonValue, that get the value of the array

Answer (score 0):

Create the whole form with `FormBuilder`. Plus, I like to separate the logic of creating an object and their form in a different class so that you can reuse them, and remember to have always your interfaces in place:

```js
    // participant.ts
    export interface Participant {
      ocupation: string;
      ocupationAddress: string;
      symptoms: Symptom[];
    }

    // symptom.ts
    export interface Symptom {
      id: number;
      value: string;
      selected: boolean;
    }

    // symptoms-builder.ts
    export class SymptomsBuilder {
      static buildForm(fb: FormBuilder, symptom: Symptom) {
        return fb.group({
          id: fb.control(symptom.id),
          value: fb.control(symptom.value),
          selected: fb.control(false)
        });
      }
    }

    // participant-builder.ts
    export class ParticipantBuilder {
      static buildForm(fb: FormBuilder, symptoms: Symptom[]) {
        return fb.group({
          occupation: fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
          occupationAddress: fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
          symptoms: fb.array(symptoms ? symptoms.map(s => SymptomsBuilder.buildForm(fb, s)) : [])
        });
      }
    }
```

So in your component you only need to initialize the Participant form:

```js
this.participantForm = ParticipantBuilder.buildForm(this.fb, symptoms);
```

When the form is fulfilled, you can get the data with `this.participantForm.value` and it'll be of type `Participant`:

```
    {
      "occupation": "2",
      "occupationAddress": "B23 IND",
      "symptoms": [
        {
          "id": 8651,
          "value": "Abdominal pain",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "id": 8646,
          "value": "Chest pain",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "id": 8642,
          "value": "Cough",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    }
```